# PostgreSQL, replace symbols before and after dot

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to replace symbols before and after dot e.g.:

```
partners.11084.RMyDaoun -> 11084
partners.360.1P7Oyag9  -> 360
partners.360  -> 360
```

What `regex` or `PostgreSQL` function can I use to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is using `split_part`.

```
select split_part(col,'.',2)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want the digits after the first dot.  If so:

```
select regexp_replace('partners.360.1P7Oyag9', '[^.]*[.]([0-9]+).*$', '\1')
```